# How does gmail browser client detect internet/server disconnect (speed and scalability)

Tags: browser, gmail, disconnect

We have an browser application (SaaS) where we would like to notify the user in the case of internet connection or server connection loss. Gmail does this very nicely, the moment I unplug the internet cable or disable network traffic it immediately says unable to reach the server and gives me a count down for retry.

What is the best way to implement something like this?  Would I want the client browser issuing AJAX requests to the application server every second, or have a separate server that just reports back "alive".  Scalability will be come an issue down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Because GMail already checks for new e-mails every some seconds and for chat information even more frequently, it can tell without a separate request if the connection is down. If you're not using Ajax for some other sort of constant update, then yes, you would just have your server reply with some sort of "alive" signal. Note that you couldn't use a separate server because of Ajax cross-domain restrictions, however.

Answer (score 0):

With the server reporting to the client (push via Comet), you have to maintain an open connection for each client. This can be pretty expensive if you have a large number of clients. Scalability can be an issue, as you mentioned. The other option is to poll. Instead of doing it every second, you can have it poll every 5-10 seconds or so.

Something else that you can look at is [Web Sockets](http://websocket.org/) (developed as part of HTML 5), but I am not sure if it is widely supported (AFAIK only Chrome supports it).